# To calculate the relative positioning of other users view port in Google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am implementing Google maps collaborator, where other users view port is represented as rectangle. If any of the users view port changes, the rectangle position gets updated.

Now i want to implement if the users view port is not on my view port, I need to create a head(black circle) representing users current view port direction. I currently have the Bounds(LatLng) position of the other users view port. In order to draw the heads, I need to calculate the angle of the current users position.
 You can refer the below image to get what i am trying to say. If the users view port is inside my view port, I can draw a head on the rectangle. But if the users view port changes, I need to calculate the distance and angle to the draw the head(black circle) relative to the users view port.
 Can you suggest me some ideas to get it done. If you have already done something related to this, Please share your ideas.

[image]

Comment: @HoangHieu: What should I do, after getting the southwest and northeast values. Can you explain me in detail?

Answer (score 1):

google map Bounds() .. get location of top,left and right,button of viewport :)

```
var latlgnBound = map.getBounds();
var NorthEast = latlgnBound.getNorthEast();
var SouthWest = latlgnBound.getSouthWest();
var maxlatX = NorthEast.lat();
var minlatX = SouthWest.lat();
var maxlngY = NorthEast.lng();
var minlngY = SouthWest.lng();

if (userlocation.locationx < maxlatX && userlocation.locationx > minlatX) {
        if (userlocation.locationy < maxlngY && userlocation.locationy > minlngY) {
                // draw a head :) .
        }
}
```

sorry if this's not what you want;

User outside;

```
**if (userlocation.locationx > maxlatX || userlocation.locationx < minlatX) 
{
// user is outside your view
}
if (userlocation.locationy > maxlngY || userlocation.locationy < minlngY) {
                // user is outside your view
        }
}**
```

Update

```
var angle = 0;
if(userlocation.locationx > maxlatX) {        
    angle += 1;
}
if(userlocation.locationy > maxlngY){
    angle += 3;
}
if(userlocation.locationx < minlatX){
    angle += 5;
}
if(userlocation.locationy < minlngY){
    angle += 7;
}
switch(angle){
    case 1:
          //User in top view port
    break;
    case 3:
          //User in left view port
    break;
    case 5:
          //User in bottom view port
    break;
    case 7:
          //User in right view port
    break;
    case 4:
          //User in top right view port
    break;
    case 6:
          //User in top left view port
    break;
    case 10:
          //User in right bottom view port
    break;
    case 12:
          //User in left bottm view port
    break;
};
```

Get user location with HTML5 :)

```
  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) { //Nếu trình duyệt định vị được
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
    //Lấy vị trí người dùng
      //Get location of user
      userlocation.locationx = position.coords.latitude;
      userlocation.locationy = position.coords.longitude

    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true); //Không xác định được vị trí
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag){
    if (errorFlag) {
          var content = "Can't get user location"; 
    } else {
          var content = "Browser doesn't support get location"; 
    }
}
```

or read more: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. As per your code, If other users are inside my view port I can draw a head(black circle). But what I need is, if other users are outside my view port(ie-some part of the map eg-USA), I should draw a head relative to their view port(need to find angle of the view port also). Thanks!!

Comment: if it outside... you can replace > to < :) and < to >

Comment: **if (userlocation.locationx > maxlatX || userlocation.locationx < minlatX) 
{
// user is outside your view
}
if (userlocation.locationy > maxlngY || userlocation.locationy < minlngY) {
                // user is outside your view
        }
}**

Comment: Thanks man!! How to find the angle between my view port and other users view port to make the head(black circle) present relative to others view port. Any suggestions?

Comment: ah. And now I understand what you want :), Check Update my answer

Comment: What is that userlocation.locationx ? How to get that value ?

Comment: Use HTML5 to get user location: Check my update answer